# Bottom Type in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, bottom-type

I'm wondering if there is [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) in the Swift language.

To weed out any confusion beforehand, [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) is a different kind than bottom type as we have it as `Void` or `()` in swift. Also `Any` is **top type**.

What I've found to be the closest, surprisingly, is `@noreturn` attribute in the form of `fatalError()` in that we can *mostly* pass this function to conform to *most* given arbitrary type.

But, of course, this is incomplete and thus a bad substitute for a true bottom type as, for example, `Nothing` in Scala, `undefined` in Haskell or even `null` in Java.

So, **is there a bottom type in Swift language?**

Comment: I cant say I have seen anything what you are asking for, in what case do you want to use this bottom type?

Comment: @Arbitur From a language's perspective, it alludes to the completeness of type system. For practical matter, you can express a type which extends all the types. This becomes useful when dealing with certain behaviours with type inference. You can refer to [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/277197/is-there-a-reason-to-have-a-bottom-type-in-a-programming-language).

Comment: @Arbitur I don't know swift but bottom types are useful in several ways: annotating the "return type" of functions that never return (e.g. they always throw), in a failure branch of a language that supports conditional types, etc. Really in much the same way the OP's answer uses that custom hacked one.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out there is no Bottom Type in swift, but we can mock its general behavior through few hacks with `@noreturn` attribute and generics as explained in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcaawcLmtBA).

```
func undefined<A>(_ message: String = "") -> A {
  fatalError("Not Implemented: \(message)")
}
```

Then we can use it to mark yet-implemented parts of our code to pass compiler errors:

```
func someComplexFunction<U: User>(u: U) -> U {
  return undefined("Do this after creating user")
}
```

Or to prove some invariances in our code:

```
let array = ["hello", "world"]
let hello: String = array.first ?? undefined("This is impossible!")
```

Comment: The talk turns out to be private.

Answer (score 0):

see [Never](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never)

Basically, you can just do

```
func foo() -> Never {
    // you can't return
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30749404)